# bukkit - Drop prevention not working?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I want to remove player's capacity to drop certain items, also removing all the drops except the ones that I want to cancel, for example: The player can't drop a sword, but when he drops a Mushroom Soup empty bowl, then clean the drop. I have two listener classes registered on the main class.

Listeners:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDropItem(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
    e.getItemDrop().remove();
}
```

PreventDropping:

```
@EventHandler(priority = EventPriority.HIGH, ignoreCancelled=false)
public void onPlayerDropItem(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getItemDrop().equals(new ItemStack(Material.MUSHROOM_SOUP)) 
        || (e.getItemDrop().equals(new ItemStack(Material.DIAMOND_SWORD)))
        || (e.getItemDrop().equals(new ItemStack(Material.IRON_SWORD)))
        || (e.getItemDrop().equals(new ItemStack(Material.TNT)))
        || (e.getItemDrop().equals(new ItemStack(Material.ARROW)))
        || (e.getItemDrop().equals(new ItemStack(Material.BOW)))
        || (e.getItemDrop().equals(new ItemStack(Material.WOOD_SWORD)))
        || (e.getItemDrop().equals(new ItemStack(Material.STONE_SWORD))))
        {
        e.setCancelled(true);
    }
}
```

Main (onLoad part):

```
@Override
public void onEnable() {        
    System.out.println("Main plugin enabled");
    getCommand("pvp").setExecutor(new PvP(this));
    getCommand("instakiller").setExecutor(new InstaKiller(this));
    getCommand("wizard").setExecutor(new Wizard(this));
    getCommand("archer").setExecutor(new Archer(this));

    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new Listeners(this), this);
    getServer().getPluginManager().registerEvents(new PreventDropping(this), this);
}
```

Sadly the server just ignores my second listener, and cleans all drops instead of making it impossible to drop the itens listed in PreventDropping. What is wrong?

Additional question: Arrows bug, as described in the comments.

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDropItem(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.DIAMOND_SWORD || 
    (e.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.IRON_SWORD)  ||
    (e.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.STONE_SWORD)  ||
    (e.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.WOOD_SWORD)  ||
    (e.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.TNT)  ||
    (e.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.BOW)  ||
    (e.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.ARROW)  ||
    (e.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.BLAZE_ROD)) {            
        e.setCancelled(true);
    } else {
        e.getItemDrop().remove();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you right, you want to disable the function to drop example mushroom soup, and remove all other items a player tries to drop. If so, why use two `PlayerDropItemEvent`? Also there is no need to create a new `ItemStack` object everytime you want to make the check, simply use:

```
@EventHandler
public void onPlayerDropItem(PlayerDropItemEvent e) {
    if(event.getItemDrop().getItemStack().getType() == Material.MUSHROOM_SOUP)) 
       /* Your code here */
    {
        e.setCancelled(true);
    } else {
        e.getItemDrop().remove();
    }
}
```

This code will cancel the drop event if the item is a mushroom soup, else it will remove the drop.

The problem with your code is that both listeners will run no matter what. This means the drop will be removed even though it's a mushroom soup. One listener will override the other.

Comment: What about the arrows? When I drop them, they duplicate themselves, and when I reach 64, they are gone @Squiddie

Comment: No, no, I've already done it. I think you should test it for yourself

Comment: When I drop arrows (already included in the if statment), they come back to the inventory and duplicate themselfs when dragged out of the inv.

Comment: Done, I did it.

Comment: Muca and @Squiddie
Please don't forget to edit both the question and the answer when you two  find a fix, in order to help future users.

Comment: @Kerookeryeah, sadly we could not find a fix, however updating CraftBukkit to something that is not 1.8 should solve it.

Comment: @MucaP The situation that you're probably in is that when arrows are dropped, the server cancels the event, making the client confuse itself.
What you can try to do is checking if the dropped item is an arrow, let the player drop them and remove the drops, then after it re-add the dropped arrows to the player (that probably won't confuse the client)

Comment: The event cancelling seems to be the problem for stackable items, as far as I can tell.